# Morse Code Converter in C

Tags: beginner, c

I'm learning C so I thought to apply it to [miniproject on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/cmd1hb/20190805_challenge_380_easy_smooshed_morse_code_1/). The smorse function takes in a string and spits out some morse code. It works if you supply the function with only lowercase letters. I feel awkward making a first for loop in my smorse function to calculate the size of buffer I need to malloc and then making a second for loop to add the characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char **master = NULL;

char* smorse(char *str) {
    int i;
    char *ele;
    int end = strlen(str);
    char *output = "";
    int totalSize = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < end; i++) {
        ele = master[(*str) - 97];
        totalSize += sizeof(ele) * sizeof(char);
        str++;
    }

    output = malloc(totalSize);
    str -= end;

    for (i = 0; i < end; i++) {
        ele = master[(*str) - 97];
        strcat(output, ele);
        str++;
    }

    return output;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    char key[] = ".- -... -.-. -.. . ..-. --. .... .. .--- -.- .-.. -- -. --- .--. --.- .-. ... - ..- ...- .-- -..- -.-- --..";
    master = (char **)malloc(26 * sizeof(char *));
    char *ele = strtok(key, " ");

    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        if (i != 0)
            ele = strtok(NULL, " ");
        master[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(ele) * sizeof(char));
        master[i] = ele;
    }

    printf("%s\n", smorse("sos"));
    printf("%s\n", smorse("daily"));
    printf("%s\n", smorse("programmer"));
    printf("%s\n", smorse("bits"));
    printf("%s\n", smorse("three"));

    free(master);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Links can rot. [Please include a description of the challenge here in your question.](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1993)

Comment: Since it's in your example, I should mention that pro-words such as SOS are transmitted without spaces, unlike ordinary words that have a dash-length pause between each letter, and three dashes pause between words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

regarding:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
```

Since the parameters are not used, the compiler will output two messages about unused parameters. Strongly suggest using the signature:

```
int main( void )
```

regarding:

```
master[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(ele) * sizeof(char));
```

1) the returned type is void* which can be assigned to any pointer. Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug. etc. Suggest removing that cast.

2) The expression: `sizeof( char )` is defined in the C standard as 1. Multiplying by 1 has no effect.

Suggest removing that expression.

3) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful. If not successful, call

```
perror( "malloc failed" );
```

to output both your error message 'malloc failed' and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`.

regarding:

```
int end = strlen(str);
```

The function: `strlen()` returns a `size_t` which is an `unsigned long int`. This will result in the compiler outputting a message about this (error prone) implicit conversion.  Suggest:

```
size_t end = strlen( str );
```

regarding:

```
totalSize += sizeof(ele) * sizeof(char);
```

the variable `ele` is a pointer, so `sizeof( ele )` results in the size of a pointer.  Depending on the underlying hardware architecture the resulting value will be 4 or 8

The array `master[]` can be easily directly coded, so no need to waste time, code, CPU cycles developing that array.  Suggest:

```
char **master[] =
{
    ".-",
    "-...",
   etc.
};
```

Then in `smorse()` a loop similar to:

```
for( size_t i = 0; str[i]; i++ )
{ 
    printf( "%s ", master[ tolower( str[i] ) ] );
}

puts( "" );
```

where the `tolower()` is from the header file: `ctype.h`

in `main()`, these statements:

```
printf("%s\n", smorse("sos"));
printf("%s\n", smorse("daily"));
printf("%s\n", smorse("programmer"));
printf("%s\n", smorse("bits"));
printf("%s\n", smorse("three"));
```

can be replaced with:

```
smorse( "sos" );
smorse( "daily" );
etc.
```

Answer (score 5):

## Memory leak

Consider this (I removed the pointless cast and identity multiplication):

> ```
>     master[i] = malloc(sizeof ele);
>     master[i] = ele;
> ```

Here, we allocate memory (if `malloc()` succeeds), but then immediately overwrite our one and only pointer to it, so we're unable to ever free it.  The first assignment should just be removed, leaving only `master[i] = ele`.

## Another memory leak:

> ```
> printf("%s\n", smorse("sos"));
> ```

The `smorse()` function returns a pointer to allocated memory, which we need to release when we've finished using it:

```
const char *m = smorse("sos");
puts(m);
free(m);
```

(The `puts()` call is exactly equivalent to using `printf("%s\n", m)`, but more readable and possible more efficient.)

## Character coding assumptions

The magic value `97` in a couple of places suggests that we're assuming that characters are encoded as ASCII values.  That's not a portable assumption: C permits a wide range of encodings.  Notably, EBCDIC systems do not have letters in the same positions as ASCII (or even as a contiguous block, so replacing with `'a'` doesn't solve the problem).

Also, there's no checking that the input to the function contains only characters that we can handle.  If we pass anything outside of the expected range, then we index `master` outside its bounds, which is Undefined Behaviour in C.  That means that the program may do anything - if we're lucky, it will simply crash, helping us to identify the problem, but there's no guarantee of that.

We ought to be converting more than just letters - digits have a standard Morse representation, as do certain other useful symbols.

## Value conversions

It seems that this has been compiled with a very low level of warnings enabled.  Building with my usual compiler flags results in over a dozen warnings, most about suspect conversions.

To pick a couple of examples:

> ```
> int end = strlen(str);
> ```

`strlen()` returns a `size_t`, which is of different signedness to `int`, and very likely to be bigger, so there's a risk of undefined behaviour here.

> ```
> char *output = "";
> ```

It's dangerous to point a modifiable pointer at constant data (a string literal is of type `char const*`).

> ```
> printf("%s\n", smorse("sos"));
> ```

Passing a string literal loses constness here - `smorse()` ought to accept pointer to `const` instead.

Comment: Excellent point about character encoding assumptions.  I made the same error in my own rewrite, but I've now fixed it with a C11 `_Static_assert`.  How would you handle, say, EBCDIC or UTF8 in a portable way?

Comment: @Edward - for single-byte encodings, I'd probably go for an array of size `UCHAR_MAX+1` and index it directly; for UTF-8 and other multi-byte encodings, read into a `wchar_t` and probably look up in a binary-searchable map (I don't think we could create that at compile-time, but we could define it with the correct elements and sort it before use).  I'm imagining an array of `struct { char index; char const* morse; }`.

Answer (score 3):

I see some things that may help you improve your program.

### Omit unused variables

Because `argc` and `argv` are unused, you could use the alternative form of `main`:

```
int main()
```

### Eliminate global variables where practical

Having routines dependent on global variables makes it that much more difficult to understand the logic and introduces many opportunities for error.  In this case `master` can easily be eliminated and I'll show below.

### Minimize the scope of variables

Somewhat related to eliminating global variables is the idea that variables should be defined in the minimum practical scope.  In this case, for instance, `key` doesn't really belong in `main` but should instead be in `smorse` as I'll describe in the next suggestion.

### Use a better data structure

Right now, `key[]` is a poorly named data structure which is then post-processed at runtime to create the data structure that's actually used.  Better would be to simply use a better data structure in the first place.  Here's how I'd do it:

```
static const char* morse[] = {".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--.."};
```

### Fix the bug

Right now, `output` is uninitialized when the call to `strcat` is made, making this *undefined behavior*.  You don't want that!  Instead, initialize `output` like this:

```
output[0] = '\0';
```

### Check for `NULL` pointers

If the call to `malloc` fails, the program will dereference a `NULL` pointer which is undefined behavior.  Instead, explicitly check for a `NULL` pointer.  You may also want to check to make sure that `smorse` has not been passed a `NULL` pointer.

### Don't leak memory

Right now, because the pointer that `smorse` returns is only passed to `printf`, it can't be freed, which means that the program leaks memory.  I'd change `main` to look like this:

```
int main() {
    const char *words[] = { "sos", "daily", "programmmer", "bits", "three", NULL };
    for (const char **word = words; *word; ++word) {
        char *morse = smorse(*word);
        puts(morse);
        free(morse);
    }
}
```

### Eliminate "magic numbers"

There are a few numbers in the code, such as `26` and `97` that have a specific meaning in their particular context.  By using named constants such as `LetterCount` or the character constant `'a'`, the program becomes easier to read and maintain.

### Use `const` where practical

The `keys` variable should never be changed, and so it should be declared `const`.  Further, it would be better to have the argument to `smorse` also be a `const char *` to indicate to the caller that the passed word is not changed.

### Perform input sanitation

The `smorse` function is not particularly robust for general user input.  For instance, if the user passes the string `"Z93!"`, this code doesn't catch the fact that these letters are out of range and attempts to address an array with a negative index value.  On my machine, this causes a segfault and a program crash.

### Create a test function

Since you have some known inputs and expected outputs, it would make sense to use those to create some test vectors that could be used by a test function.

Answer (score 2):

### main()

It looks like this line it trying to allocate some memory to store one of the morse code strings (e.g., "-...").

```
master[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(ele) * sizeof(char));
```

However, `ele` is a char* and `sizeof(char)` is 1.  So, this allocates memory for one char*, not enough to store a string of up to 4 char plus a terminating NULL.  To get the length of the string pointed to by `ele` use `strlen()`.

A pointer to the allocated memory is then stored in `master[i]`.  But, the very next line:

```
master[i] = ele;
```

overwrites that pointer with the pointer returned by `strtok()`.  The malloced memory is goes unused and un-freed.  And is in fact not needed.

This loop could be written like:

```
int i = 0;
for (char *ele = strtok(key, " "); ele; ele = strtok(NULL, " ")) {
    master[i++] = ele;
}
```

Or better yet, just hard code `master`, like user3629249 said.

`smorse()` returns a pointer to malloc'd memory that is never freed.

### smorse()

For proper morse code, you need a short space, or break, between letters and a slightly longer one between words.  The inter-letter space can be a space at the end of each master code.

The longest morse code string is 5 characters (including a space at the end of each code), so you could just do:

```
output = (char *)malloc(5 * strlen(str))
```

In this loop, `i` is never used:

```
for (i = 0; i < end; i++) {
    ele = master[(*str) - 97];
    strcat(output, ele);
    str++;
}
```

It could be coded like:

```
for (char *c = str; *c; c++) {
    ele = master[(*c) - 97];
    strcat(output, ele);
}
```